# Como adicionar linhas manualmente em um datagriedview preenchido com dados do MySql

Tags: c#, datagridview

Tenho um DataGridView em que preencho ele com dados de uma tabela do mysql e depois preciso adicionar linhas com dados de algumas textbox, quando tento retorna o seguinte erro: "Não é possível adicionar linhas programaticamente à coleção de linhas de DataGridView quando o controle é associado a dados".

meu código :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{
    Hide();
    FormPai.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(txtCod.Text, servicosBox.Text, txtPreco.Text);
    FormPai.dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve instanciar uma coluna antes, recomendo criar uma função para isso.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hide();
    CriarRow(/*DataSource usada*/);
    FormPai.dataGridView1.Refresh();
}

private void CriarRow(DataTable tabela)
{
    DataRow row = tabela.NewRow();
    row[0] = txtCod.Text;
    row[1] = servicosBox.Text;
    row[2] = txtPreco.Text;
    tabela.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: Olá Francisco, deu o seguinte erro quando tentei usar o seu código: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' to 'System.Data.DataTable'

Comment: Eu errei, você tem que passar o datasource nos parâmetros, ao invez do datagridview.

Comment: Não entendi essa parte de passar o DataSource nos parâmetros, eu usei o seguinte código pra preencher o meu DataGridView:     MySqlCommand comando2 = new MySqlCommand("select cod,servico,preco from guardaservicos where codOS=@codOS ", conect.conexao);
                comando2.Parameters.Add("@codOS", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lblNumOS.Text;
                MySqlDataAdapter adaptador2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(comando2);
                DataTable data2 = new DataTable();
                adaptador2.Fill(data2);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = data2;

Comment: Não achei o que eu tenho q por como parâmetro ali.

Comment: No seu caso, a variável `data2`, pois ela é sua DataSource

Comment: Muito Obrigado,funcionou.

Comment: Não se esqueça de marcar a resposta como correta para fechar o tópico e também ajudar quem tem o mesmo problema!